# Comma Usage in this sentence

Tags: phrases, commas

"The Group members shall consist of representatives who will coordinate and facilitate the transfer of knowledge and expertise, taking into consideration the interest or functions involving the following agencies:". Is the comma after "expertise" good usage? I added it because when spoken, there is a pause. Now I'm having doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma there is fine. Though I might suggest adding a "while" after the comma as a conjunction to join the sentences together better.